# How to solidify?

Tags: modifiers

I'd like to solidify and bevel this object, but I can't seem to get it right when I apply both those modifiers. The back face seems to get messed up. I need this exact shape. How do I go about doing this?

I've attached the .blend file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c0k079ernsa4q9/How%20to%20solidify.blend?dl=0)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't see what is messed up here? Could you add details?

Comment: Hi. Did you have a look at the .blend file? When I apply the Solidify and Bevel modifiers, in that order, the back portion ends up looking distorted, as in the third image. I don't know how to adjust the topology of the mesh in order to get it to look clean when the modifiers are applied.

Comment: You mean at the fold corner?

Comment: Oh ok... you mean some part is not straight as in the original mesh, but there is an angle from the corner to the inside, that's is?

Comment: A possibility is to invert the thickness value... but that depends on what you want to do globally about the mesh dimensions.

Comment: Yes, when I apply the solidify mod. a part of the mesh at the corner fold doesn't solidify symmetrically. I've tried various combinations of options available in the solidify mod but nothing seems to work. There's no doubles at all. No clipping. I figure the issue is with the topology of the mesh. I just don't know how to rework it.

Comment: I've tried inverting the thickness value as well, but that still doesn't fix the issue. It'd be great if someone could take a look at the .blend file because it'd be much easier to understand the odd deformation I'm getting. Also, I'm relatively new to Blender, so my apologies if I'm not being more descriptive with proper terminology.

Comment: I've downloaded the file. It's more complex than it seems, using the modifiers. am wondering if there is another way than modeling it manually.

Comment: well, it seems to be a normal problem (don't know why I have not seen that sooner...). In edit mode select all and ctrl+shift+N. Though, thickness will overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is a normal issue in the original file, solidify modifier can't work properly (it seems) in this situation, as either thickness will overlap or solidify modifier will give unwanted geometry.

[image]

So I think the solution is to model manually what should be given by the solidify modifier and use the bevel modifier on it.

The easiest way can be to start with the main profile and extrude it, and use a mirror:

[image]

The corners are made by squares of the wanted thickness (unfortunately, you cannot tune the thickness afterwards).

[image]

The background part is done in a second step, extruding only what corresponds to it:

[image]

The result, using the bevel (with angle) seems to give the wanted straight geometry:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's doing that because the vertices aren't attached.

The point circled in red is only connected to 2 edges, not the 3rd one that runs across the entire length of your object. The ones circled in blue, I'm not sure if you wanted those attached as well or left hanging. There will be a gap if you leave them be though.
[image]

To fix it you can subdivide it to add another vertice, then merge that vertice with the one circled in red.